# How to store the option selected from drop down box in a variable in selenium?

Tags: selenium-ide

I selected the option from drop down box using id. Now i want to store the value selected from drop-down box in a variable, to use the value in other places.

Answer (score 3):

```
<tr>
    <td>storeSelectedValue</td>
    <td>id=Month</td>
    <td>monthvalue</td>
</tr>
```

We can use storeSelectedValue command get the value selected in drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

I have sample code for you..(gmail registration -> drop-down for gender). I have selected male option

```
storeText  |  //div[@id='Gender']/div  |  gender
echo       | ${gender}
```

Comment: no. I tried out this, it gives me all the possible options in the drop down list.

Comment: [info] Executing: |echo | ${year} | |
[info] echo: Select Year 2012 2011

Answer (score 0):

With this HTML structure:

```
<div id="test">
    <label for="merchantType">Merchant Type</label>
    <select>
        <option value="Firm">Firm</option>
        <option value="Institution">Institution</option>
        <option value="Association">Association</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

... you could for example store the value of a specific option using:

```
storeText   |   //div[@id='test']/select/option[2]   |   myvalue
```

=> Here it will get the 2nd option value. This can be handy in loops using for instance "option[${i}]" to get all values in distinct variables.

You can also select a specific option using:

```
select   |   //div[@id='test']/select   |   index=${i}
```